# How to set creator Google calendar event via API v3

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, service-application

I am creating events via the Google Calendar API v3 with service application. I'm authenticating my program via OAuth 2.0 credentials obtained through the API console.

Everything works well so far, but I see the service account email address as my event creator. How can I set another email address as the event creator?

Comment: To change the event creator from service account to another user, you have to impersonate the user. check this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount which allows to this user to create events in the calendar

Comment: I have the same issue in php.I need session email id as the event creator in google calendar. How can i do this using OAuth 2.0 service account?.Plz help me

Comment: @SGC how would we go about setting the impersonated email/name if we are using json file instead of the P12 file?